# Como recarregar config.json no bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, github

Estou tentando gerar um gist com o config.json para dar reload no bootstrap sem perder as alterações que já fiz.

Então criei um gist:

https://gist.github.com/aymone/dba37043a860d4f0abb1

Mas ao tentar carregar no bootstrap desta forma:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/dba37043a860d4f0abb1

e também desta forma:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/id=dba37043a860d4f0abb1

Está gerando um erro 404 alguém sabe o que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma correta é: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=dba37043a860d4f0abb1

Note o ponto de interrogação logo depois da última barra, e antes do parâmetro id.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!